# Double sum computation in R

Tags: r

I'm having problem writing the following double sum into a function in r:
[image: s]

where the I function is an indicator function and we have n observations x_1...x_n.

I tried something like this

```
sum( (x <= t) / (sum((x<=x)))^2)
```

Comment: Can you give a reproducable example? [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
sumiI <- function(xi, x) sum(xi<=x)
sum(1/sapply(x[x<=t], FUN=sumI, x=x))
```